# $\pm 1$ valued vectors in an arbitrary subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, geometry, additive-combinatorics

In a paper I have read on random Bernoulli matrices it was stated that for any subspace $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension at most $l$ one has:
$$|V\cap \{\pm 1\}^n|\leq 2^l$$
With no proof. A [reference was provided](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316588900465).
However, the claim does not appear there.

How should this be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the solid $n$ dimensional hypercube $Q$ with side length $4$, with vertices $\{\pm 2\}^n$. We can partition this into $2^n$ sub-cubes with side length $2$, with a cube $Q_i$ centered at vector $i$ for each $i\in \{\pm 1\}^n$.

Let $S=Q\cap V$. For each $j\in V\cap \{\pm1\}^n$, let $S_j=Q_j\cap V$. Note that $S_j$ and $S$ are both sections of an $l$-dimensional plane through the center of a cube, the difference being that the cube for $S_j$ has half the side length for the cube for $S$. Letting  $\def\vol{\text{vol}}\vol$ denote $l$-dimensional volume, this proves

- $\sum_{j\in  V\cap \{\pm1\}^n} \vol(S_j)\le \vol(S)$
- $\vol(S_j)=2^{-l}\vol(S)$, because $S_j$ is congruent to $S$ scaled down by a factor of $2$.

Combined, these prove $|V\cap \{\pm1\}^n|\le 2^l$.

I believe this volume argument can be modified to prove the same result is true even when $V$ is an arbitrary affine subspace, not just a linear one.

Answer (score 2):

By an elementary duality argument, there is a subset $A$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that the natural projection $\Pi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^A$ (that selects coordinates indexed by $A$) induces an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^A$ (in particular, the cardinal of $A$ is $\ell$). Since $\Pi$ sends $\{\pm 1\}^n \cap V$ into $\{\pm 1\}^{A}$, and is injective on $\{\pm 1\}^n \cap V$ (because it is injective on $V$), we see that the cardinal of $\{\pm 1 \}^n \cap V$ is less than $2^\ell$.

Comment: This only applies when $V$ is the span of one or more standard basis vectors. For example, when $n=4$, and $V=\{x: x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0\}$, then $V\cap \{\pm1\}^4$ are the vertices of an octahedron, and it does not project to $\{-1,1\}^A$ for any $|A|=3$.

Comment: You do not need to assume that $V$ is the span of standard basis vectors. For instance, in your case, you can project $V$ on the first three coordinates and you get an isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. An element of $V \cap \{\pm 1\}^4$ is sent via this isomorphism into $\{\pm 1\}^3$. Notice however that it is false that  $V \cap \{\pm 1\}^4$  maps onto $\{\pm 1\}^3$ by projecting on the first three coordinates (but it does not matter, since we only want an upper bound).

Comment: @MikeEarnest I guess that what you did not understand is the duality argument, it goes as follow. If you look at the linear forms on $V$ corresponding to the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then they generate the dual of $V$ (because the intersection of their kernels is zero-dimensional). Hence, you may choose $\ell$ coordinates such that the corresponding linear forms form a basis of the dual of $V$. It easily implies that the corresponding projection is an isomorphism.

Comment: I see now, my comment was completely wrong and did not correspond to what I was confused about, but your last comment addressed my confusion.